# List all homebrew packages explicitly installed by the user (without deps)

Tags: homebrew

Is there a way to list all the homebrew packages explicitly installed by the user (they they installed directly using `brew install`)?

Note `brew leaves` doesn't do this. Over time formula can change change their dependencies leaving orphaned leaves that were never explicitly installed by the user or adding dependencies on previously explicitly installed packages.

Answer (score 21):

I like [@orlp's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/438632/482937) solution using jq, but I should mention that you can also use

```
brew leaves --installed-on-request
```

to exclude orphaned packages from `brew leaves` output. See [docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#leaves---installed-on-request---installed-as-dependency)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: Best answer, thanks!

Comment: This gives the wrong answer if anything that you installed is no longer a leaf. This will happen if you install something that has a dependency on something you installed manually.

Comment: @Inigo That's right, solution using`brew info` is more correct

Comment: `brew info` doesn't give any info on this.  @orlp's answer, `brew bundle dump --file -`  is the best as it includes things you installed manually even if they are no longer leaves, in addition to taps and casks you installed. I wrote up a whole analysis in [my answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994717/8910547).  It's very easy to create an alias so you don't have to remember that long command.

Answer (score 17):

### Simple mode using `brew bundle`

We can list all taps, formulae and casks that were added by the user on stdout:

```bsh
brew bundle dump --file -
```

Or we can do it manually, without using `brew bundle`.

### Listing all `brew` taps

```bsh
brew tap
```

### Listing all `brew` formulae installed on request

This ignores any formulae that were added automatically as dependencies, but unlike `brew leaves` will still show any packages that are dependencies if you installed them manually as well, and avoids listing 'orphaned' packages:

```bsh
brew info --json=v2 --installed \
    | jq -r '.formulae[]|select(any(.installed[]; .installed_on_request)).full_name'
```

### Listing all `brew` casks installed

At the time of writing (2022-03-20) `brew` doesn't keep track of which casks were installed on request, but few if any casks are dependencies for other casks/formulae, so we can simply list them all:

```bsh
brew list --cask -l1
```

Comment: Nice. I prefer your info/jq method of finding formulas installed explicitly.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It lists `glib` in all cases, although I didn't install glib explicitly. Where as `brew leaves` does not list it.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you can use `brew bundle`:

```
brew bundle dump --file /tmp/x
brew bundle list --file /tmp/x --formula
```

the temporary file can be avoided using pipes

```
brew bundle dump --file - | brew bundle list --file - --formula
```

Comment: Also doesn't work for me. It lists `glib` in all cases, although I didn't install glib explicitly. Where as `brew leaves` does not list it.